# Bessel-(LIKE) Inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $H$ be the Hilbert space, and let $M_1,M_2,...,M_n$ be mutually orthogonal closed linear subspaces of $H$. If $P_{M_i}x=x_i$, then show that

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\|x_i\|^2\leq\|x\|^2 ,$$

The equality hold iff $x$ is in the linear span of the $M_i$. What do we expect the result when $M_1,M_2,...,M_n, ....$ is an infinite sequence.

Comment: looks like the pythagorean theorem

Comment: @Lemur actually I searched a lot around the topic I did not find anything and have no idea for proving it hence posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that "mutually closed" means "mutually orthogonal". Otherwise the result is trivially false if you take $M_1=M_2=\cdots=M_n$.

Let $\{z_{jk}\}_k$ be an orthonormal basis of $M_j$, for each $j$. Then
$$
P_{M_j}x=\sum_{k=1}^{l_j}\langle x,z_{jk}\rangle\, z_{jk},
$$
and
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n\|P_{M_j}x\|^2=\sum_{j=1}^n\langle P_{M_j}x,P_{M_j}x\rangle=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^{l_j}\sum_{h=1}^{l_j}\langle x,z_{jk}\rangle\,\overline{\langle x,z_{jh}\rangle}\,\langle z_{jk},z_{jh}\rangle
\\=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^{l_j}|\langle x,z_{jk}\rangle|^2\leq\|x\|^2.
$$
The last inequality holds because $\{z_{jk}\}_{j,k}$ can be extended to an orthonormal basis of all of $H$. When $x$ is in the span of the $M_j$ then $x$ is in the span of $\{z_{jk}\}_{j,k}$ and so we have equality.

Comment: First, thanks for the answer, 2nd, thanks for letting me know that I had a mistake in the question. Yes, $M_i$ should be pairwise orthogonal.

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing more than a reformulation of Martin Argerami's answer. Let $N\in\{1, 2\ldots +\infty\}$ and consider the (possibly infinite) family of orthogonal subspaces $\{M_j\ :\ 1\le j\le N\}$. Write $P_j$ to denote orthogonal projection onto $M_j$ and $P_\bot$ to denote orthogonal projection onto $\left(\bigoplus_{j=1}^N M_j \right)^\bot$. We therefore have, for any vector $x\in H$, 
$$
x=\sum_{j=1}^N P_j x + P_\bot x, $$
Note that, if $N=\infty$, the sum is actually a series which converges absolutely (with respect to the norm of $H$). Expanding the squared norm $\lVert x \rVert^2$ we get 
$$ \tag{1}
\begin{split}
\lVert x\rVert^2&=\left\langle \sum_{j=1}^N P_j x + P_\bot x, \sum_{j=1}^N P_j x + P_\bot x\right\rangle \\ 
&=\sum_{j=1}^N \lVert P_j x\rVert^2 + \lVert P_\bot x\rVert^2.
\end{split}$$
Note that in the right hand side all mixed terms $\langle P_j x, P_kx\rangle,\ j\ne k$  and $\langle P_j x, P_\bot x\rangle$ have vanished because of orthogonality.

The equation $(1)$ is called a *Pythagorean expansion*, for its analogy with the well-known formula expressing the squared length of an hypotenuse in terms of the legs. The sought Bessel-like inequality is an easy consequence of that, obtained by just discarding the term $\lVert P_\bot x\rVert^2$. The equality case is also easily characterized, as equality in Bessel inequality holds iff $P_\bot x=0$, which means exactly that $x$ belongs to $\bigoplus_{j=1}^N M_j$.

Comment: Dead Giuseppe Thanks for you reply. Nice answer